# How to make Julia verbose at interpreter startup?

Tags: julia

Like `python -d` (debug/verbose) spews lots of information at interpreter startup, how can I achieve something similar with Julia? (My specific problem is to find out why, when called from python (`pyjulia`), Julia 0.6dev can't load `boot.jl`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no verbose startup mode. You can, however, run julia and/or the python process loading `libjulia` under gdb. Just spitballing, not being able to find `boot.jl` sounds like a path problem. I'm also somewhat surprised that `libjulia` would be trying to find or load `boot.jl` in the first place, since that file and many others are usually baked into a system image file with a `.ji` extension (`sys.ji` previously and `inference.ji` more recently).